# How to make the Calendar in ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, calendar

Can any one get me the idea to get the Calendar functionality which is similar to iCal App'

Can any one get me the sample code for that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why ? For learning or to create Yet Another Calendar App ?

Comment: its to add the calendar UI in my app,and would like to add the events for each days by the user.

Comment: then you have add some framework those provide you calendar use this source code for your calendar https://github.com/briancollins/Kal